# Embedded Select for From value

Tags: postgresql

Having difficulty framing my question for Google.

I am trying to embed a select statement which pulls partition table names from a view.  I want to cycle through these tables and do a search within them for a value count.

I have:

`SELECT COUNT(objectA) 
 FROM (SELECT partitiontablename 
       FROM partitions 
       WHERE tablename = 'x') 
 AS tableNameQuery 
 WHERE objectB = 1`

I am getting `ERROR:  column "objectB" does not exist`

The partitions tables do have objectB (they are the same table structure).  Can you guide me to what i am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I had to change some stuff for privacy.  But I did edit the error string incorrectly. It is correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(objectA) 
FROM (
    SELECT partitiontablename, objectB, objectA
    FROM partitions 
    WHERE tablename = 'x'
) AS tableNameQuery 
WHERE objectB = 1
```

The subquery in your query retrieves only `partitiontablename` column, so the outer query sees only that column, but doesn't see `objectB`.
The same problem is with `objectA` used in COUNT() in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply kordirko.  I tried the code and it does not work.  However I believe I need to be more clear.  partitiontablename represents a list of tables that I want to run the outer query against.  Partitions is a list of table names.  Therefor objectA and objectB do not exist in partitions, they exist in the tables for which I am trying to call.

I am wondering if this is even the correct way to do this?

Comment: OK, I think I understand now the problem. You are trying to get table names from `partitions` table, then read `objectA` and `objectB` from these tables. This cannot be done in plain SQL, you need a procedure and  dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you Kordirko.  If you make a comment I'll mark it it as Best Answer!.

I will now be looking to learn cursors.